# Yaml file with constructor and setting attributes not working

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I would like to create some java objects with my Yaml-File. Here is the source code:

```
package foo;

public class Sample {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    private Integer value;

    public Sample(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

A very simple java class. Here is the Yaml file:

```
mySample: !!foo.Sample [ 'Name', 'Description' ]
  value: 123
```

The exception is:

```
while parsing a block mapping
 in 'string', line 4, column 1:
    mySample: !!foo.Sample [ 'Name', ...
```

But if I remove the setting of the "value", it works. Is it not possible to create a object with another constructor as the default and after that setting some member attributes?

This runs perfectly, but with no value for "value":

```
mySample: !!foo.Sample [ 'Name', 'Description' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is CompactObjectNotation, a feature in SnakeYAML that is outside the spec.

https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/CompactObjectNotation